# List with two values in every List Item

Tags: shell, csv, array, for

I want to store a list with name and email address and use it in the single for loop. And I want to do it in Shell.

Knowing that shell list has a white space separator

```
list = "john, john@gmail.com" "doe, doe@outlook.com" "jenny, jenny@another.domain"

for i,j in $list; do
    echo "Dear $i, email text" | mail -s "Hello $i" $j
done
```

this should work as

```
echo "Dear john, email text" | mail -s "Hello john" john@gmail.com
```

Also if I want to create this list in a separate csv file, how will I use that? E.g

```
name, email
john, john@gmail.com
jenny, jenny@another.domain
doe, doe@outlook.com
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your shell supports them, you could use an associative array for the first case:

```
declare -A list=([john]="john@gmail.com" [doe]="doe@outlook.com" [jenny]="jenny@another.domain")

for i in "${!list[@]}"; do 
  echo "Dear $i, email text" | mail -s "Hello $i" "${list[$i]}"
done
```

For the second case, a while loop:

```
while IFS=, read -r i j; do
  echo "Dear $i, email text" | mail -s "Hello $i" "$j"
done < file.csv
```

(this assumes your file is correctly formatted CSV, without a header line).

Comment: Also assumes space at the start of the email address is ok, but that's just an issue with the format of the input data.

Comment: @Kusalananda so I should not use whitespace in the csv file. Can I use this while loop with file as "john", "john@gmail.com"?

Comment: @RohailAbbas If there's no spaces around the comma, and if the quotes are not in the data. The comma is the field delimiter in CSV files. Anything that is not a comma is data, including the quotes, at least the way this answer is parsing it.

Comment: I got my answer, thanks.
Just for the clarity, if I have comma in the data, how can I handle that? 
Can't I use quotes or double quotes?

`"john", "john@gmail.com, john@outlook.com"`
`"jane", "jane@another.domain"`

Comment: @RohailAbbas if you have anything more complex than simple `name,value` pairs then I would suggest using a specialist parsing library or tool - look at Perl's Text::CSV module and/or the Python-based csvkit